# pytest-bdd StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found:

Tags: testing, automated-tests, pytest, bdd

I have created pytest BDD framework but when I am adding new feature file and test file. I can use shared steps but can't use other steps which are defined in the exact feature file. Please help how can I figure out this.

[image]

[image]

This shared given step which takes token is working but other step which belongs to exact feature doesn't works.

[image]

[image]